# Displaying Google Maps with only solid colors

Tags: google-maps

I was wondering if there was a way wherein I could output the map (using the Google Maps Static API) to display the map colors using only solid colors. That is to say, no different shades of any color. For example, as default, small roads would be pure white, big roads would be pure yellow (with no shades of yellow) and highways would be pure orange.

I need to make a occupancy grid map and was planning on making it with the colors of the map instead of plotting it in matlab etc.

I can clarify any doubts you may have about my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [this](http://googlemapscolorizr.stadtwerk.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I had manipulate some map colour schemes a while back.

I created this fiddle which might be of use to you..

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/6hsAe/

And then referred to this wizard which helped me get the result I wanted..

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Not 100% sure if you will be able to do what you want, but this may help.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Would you happen to know what I should put in the wizard in order to get the solid colors?

Comment: How do you mean exactly, as colors are generally solid. Do you mean remove the strokes?

Comment: Yeah, I basically want to remove the shading etc, such that I get a map in which the white is 255,255,255 ; the yellow is 255,255,0 and orange is 255,165,0

Note that this has to be done using only Google Maps Static API, so I'd need to manipulate the URL in order to do that

Comment: Oh yes, that's great! Any idea how I can get the same effect using the Google Maps Static API?

Thank you so much by the way- you've made my life so much easier!

Comment: Hmmm in the wizard it says just click the Static Map button, but with all those stylers, the button is not active - so maybe there are limitations to it :/ i'm not sure. Anyway good luck with trying to crack it.